# Is there quick way to know what cell is out of device screen in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have tableView with a lot of cells. I need to remove cells, which user passes while scrolling the tableView.

**cellForRowAtIndexPath** is called when user scroll to this cell to perform its content and the **question** *is there similar method to know what cells are out of the screen while scrolling?*

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The tableView will only create as many cells as it needs for a screenful (plus a bit) of data, and will re-use them for scrolling. You shouldn't need to do anything with cells that are scrolled off screen.

Comment: i don't need to anything with cells which are out of screen and it works, but if there are really a lot of cells with heavy content i need to delete this content because it takes a lot of memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `UITableView`'s `visibleCells` method. It'll tell which ones *are* visible. Then I'm assuming you know how many total cells there are and you can do the logic to work out which ones are not visible.

Comment: I saw this method, but i think its not the right way on each cellFor to analize which cells are out of the screen, which are deleted ,which are not

Comment: I don't quite follow. What do you mean by which ones are deleted? You'll get one `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call for each of the cells which the table view has decided to ask you for. Don't use it to determine visibility. Use `visibleCells` for that.

Comment: sory, not deleted, i don't want to make any delete of cells, just to make all of the which are out of screen empty( delete content).

Comment: The ones that are off screen will not actually be there though. UIKit will have taken them off the screen and put them in the reuse pool for that table view. Why are you worried about the ones off the screen?

Comment: Cells are in the pool ,but the content is not deleted, that is why application is heavy only because there are a lot of cells, so the best way is to delete unnecessary content.

Comment: `UITableViewCell`s get sent the `prepareForReuse` message before they are put in the pool. Perhaps you should subclass `UITableViewCell`, implement `prepareForReuse` and release what you need to.

Comment: I solved the problem just watching in what way(up or down) tableView is scrolled. In method cellFor... just for (indexpath.row + or - needed length) delete needed content.    My cells are already subclasses of the cell, thanks for answer i will look for prepareForReuse.

Comment: Really thanks for prepareForReuse) Works exactly what i wanted